# JqueryTools Scrollable: change Scroll-Steps after button click

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-tools

I love the scrollable plugin from "[jquery tools](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html)". works great so far. Just noticed, that changing the scrolling steps isn't working when triggered by a button.
Though it is working on "document load".
I want to change the amount of items scrolled after a button click. But this fails.

This works right after "doc load":

```
$("#scrollable").scrollable({
size: 5;
});
```

But then when doing it from a button-click it doesnt:

```
        $("#mybutton").click(function(event) {

        // approach 1
        var api = $("#scrollable").data("scrollable");
        api.size = 1;

        // approach 2
        $("#scrollable").data("scrollable").size = 1;

        // approach 3
        $("#scrollable").scrollable({size: 1}) ;
      });
```

Either one of the approaches should work, but it doesnt....
Seems after doc load scrollable doesnt allow me to change "size".
Any solution?

Dom

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle I created for this problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/NwhYD/1/

Answer (score 0):

Works... http://jsfiddle.net/NwhYD/2/

This solved the problem:

```
jQuery(".scrollable").data("scrollable").getConf().size=1;
```